# IIS not showing anything when I browse to "localhost"

Tags: asp.net, iis, deployment

I've been trying to use my computer as a web server so that I can host a website on it. I've got IIS installed and configured. I must have done something that I shouldn't have done, because whenever I try to hit my local host with just a simple webpage I get a 404 error back. I think I don't have everything in IIS configured right. Little help?

Answer (score 0):

If you are able to get a 404 back, IIS must be running fine. Try to make sure your site is pointing at a folder where the file you are looking for is.  i.e.  If you are trying to go to `http://localhost/test.html` then make sure the site is configured to use the folder where test.html is.  Or if you haven't made any changes to IIS site, put your file (eg: test.html) in `C:\inetpub\wwwroot`, and try again.